# Can a community user do mass edit from list views

Tags: community

Can a community user do mass edits from a list view?

Comment: Can you say what you mean by mass edit? Do you mean a Visualforce page that performs some action on records from a list view or do you mean inline editing in a list view?

Comment: i mean editing more than 2 records,by selecting 2 and doing inline editing from list view.so that changes are applied to both.

Answer (score 2):

Communities users have restricted permissions compared to a standard internal user but there is nothing prevent them from doing edits, either inline in the list view or via some Visualforce page acting on a list of sObjects that come from a list view, as long as that user has permission to edit that object.

All custom objects (not tied by master-detail to a standard object) can be made editable by Communities users, for example, and certain standard objects can be made editable as well. For a good overview of object CRUD permission by Salesforce license, check out this matrix from Wes Nolte at tquila:

https://docs.google.com/a/salesforce.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuSsu_7yn04IdDRxajlZM196aGM1bUx2MHlMdERraHc&usp=sharing#gid=0

Comment: Mass edits from list view is a permission enabled in profiles.and community users(with partner community licensed profiles) doesnt have this option..so i am not sure  how it possible,to select more than 2 items from a list view and edit it in one go..

Comment: I do not see that option, you are right.